# Inno Setup "Wrong Parameter" (Wusa.exe and .msu)

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to create a Setup using Inno Setup. Because I have to install a `.msu` file, I use the `Wusa.exe`.

The important code line:

```
Filename: {sys}\wusa.exe; WorkingDir: {app}; Parameters: {app}\Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64.msu;
```

Every time I launch the program, it gives me this error and I couldn't figure out a solution yet:

> 2147942487 "Wrong Parameter."(Commandline:""C:\Windows\system32\wusa.exe" C:\Program Files (x86)\Phone-O-Mat\Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64.msu")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing quotes around the file name. You need these, as the `{app}` resolves to a path with spaces:

```
Filename: {sys}\wusa.exe; WorkingDir: {app}; \
    Parameters: """{app}\Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64.msu"""
```

Comment: Now I changed it to this: `Filename: "{sys}\wusa.exe"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; Parameters: "{app}\Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64.msu";` Still not working, same error :( Nevertheless thank you :)

Comment: Sorry, I've used wrong syntax. Fixed now. You have to use 3 double quotes.

Comment: Nice! Thank you :)

Comment: silent install: ```/quiet /norestart ```